# Receive JSON Object from ReactJS on my Django BackEnd

Tags: json, django, reactjs

I'm trying to get a list of upload files and at the same time a JSON Object from ReactJS FrontEnd to my Django BackEnd,

in **views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def simple_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        print("REQUEST POST: ", request.POST)
        print("REQUEST META: ", request.META)
        #received_json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        #print("JSON DATA: ",received_json_data)

        #print(received_json_data)

        gps = request.FILES['gps']

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename_gps = fs.save(gps.name, gps)
        print(fs.url(filename_gps))
        gps_json = json.load(open(fs.url(filename_gps)[1:]))
        print("GPS: ",gps_json)
```

in **my_template.html**

if have a dropzone

```
<div class="dropzone">

  <div class="content">
    <img src="{% static 'core/img/upload.svg' %}" class="upload">
    <span class="filename"></span>

    <input type="file" name="myfile" class="input" multiple>
    <input type="file" name="myjson" class="input">

  </div>
</div>
```

Edit:

JSON Object from FrontEnd ReactJS:

```
var jsonGPS = {"latitude":123456,"longitude":123456}
form.append("gps",jsonGPS)
```

Issue 1:

```
[2018-08-17 20:51:25 +0000] [31996] [DEBUG] POST /uploads/simple/
Internal Server Error: /uploads/simple/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miguel/virtualizacion/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/miguel/virtualizacion/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/miguel/virtualizacion/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miguel/myapp/object-detection-uploader/uploads/core/views.py", line 36, in simple_upload
    gps = request.FILES['gps']
  File "/home/miguel/virtualizacion/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
MultiValueDictKeyError: "'gps'"
```

Issue 2 (After apply Jerin's Solution):

```
[2018-08-18 09:29:15 +0000] [24055] [DEBUG] POST /uploads/simple/
Internal Server Error: /uploads/simple/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miguel/virtualizacion/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/miguel/virtualizacion/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/miguel/virtualizacion/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miguel/myapp/object-detection-uploader/uploads/core/views.py", line 31, in simple_upload
    gps = json.loads(gps_str)  # 'gps' as dict (python)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Is this a format issue?

Comment: What problem are you facing now?

Comment: What is ur actual issue?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge the Issue has been added

Comment: are you using `Django Rest Framework`?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge No, just Django 1.98

Comment: the exception raises on `gps_json = json.load(open(fs.url(filename_gps)[1:]))` this line..... You didn't added those snippet

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sorry, it was another code trying to do what I want. I just updated the code and issue.

Comment: What kind of file is **`gps`** here? Image? pdf?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge just a json object, like: `{"lat:12345","long:12345"}`

Comment: file containing `JSON` , right?

Comment: apart from that, if it's a simple json like `{"lat:12345","long:12345"}` this, then why would you use a `file` ? You could pass it as json payload. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorgeThat's the point, `JSON OBJECT`, not `FILE`. What should I change?

Comment: @Ambigus9 Can you brief the logic you want to achieve?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sure, I just want to get a simple json that is posted by FrontEnd to my Django's BackEnd. and the same FrontEnd send me a list of images to upload them to my server. I want both things at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178239/discussion-between-ambigus9-and-jerin-peter-george).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


@csrf_exempt
def simple_upload(request):
    gps_str = request.POST.get('gps', None)
    if gps_str is None:
        return HttpResponse("'gps' key not found in request payload")
    gps = json.loads(gps_str)  # 'gps' as dict (python)
    files = request.FILES  # you will get all files as dict like object



    return HttpResponse("some response")
```

Comment: I wouldn’t advise making a POST endpoint csrf exempt, unless you have something in place to monitor the usage of this endpoint and you understand the security implications (or have at least mitigated against them).

Comment: I'm not preferring that either. I focused on upload part of the view fucntion

Comment: Apologies - should have commented above.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge After apply your solution currently i'm getting `ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to the question?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Updated issue details

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Yes, it is! `{
  "gps":{
  "latitude":123456,
  "longitude":1234567
  }
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178261/discussion-between-ambigus9-and-jerin-peter-george).